# Laravel doesn't recognize a valid route

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel for a Cat Management App and I'm having trouble creating Cats as Laravel returns a 404 for my routes.

```
Route::get('cats/create', function() {
    $cat = new Cat;
    return View::make('cats.edit')
    ->with('cat',$cat)
    ->with('method','post');
});
```

This route returns a stack trace which throws a not found HTTP exception.

Why Isn't this working?
The address I'm typing is

> localhost:8000/cats/create

This is the result of PHP artisan routes.
[image: PHP ARTISAN ROUTES]

Comment: Are other routes working? If not, it might be a problem with URL rewriting.

Comment: Yes , other routes are working

Comment: Perhaps it's a conflict with other routes then. If you have routes that match more than one pattern declared in your `Route::get()` declarations, that can lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: try running `php artisan routes` from the command line and see if everything looks correct.

Comment: What does php artisan routes show?

Comment: GET|HEAD cats/create        |      | Closure

Comment: Check your .htaccess is working

Comment: @SimonBennett How would I check that? My other routes are all working

Comment: Not to be a whiner .But I Have A Deadline, I would post a bounty now if it were allowed

Comment: hmm have a look in the loads php artisan tail

Comment: Try posting the **full** output of `php artisan routes` - the more info we have the better.

Comment: Added A pic with PHP ARTISAN ROUTES OUTPUT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rearrange your route definitions, so that the route for cats/create is defined before the route for cats/{cat}.

Comment: To elaborate, routes are matched in the order they are defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following routes in your application:

```
GET|HEAD cats/{cat}
GET|HEAD cats/create
```

If you hit `http://localhost/cats/create` that's going to get matched by the **first** route. It looks like you're using [Route Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding) so your application is trying to interpret "create" as the ID for an instance of the `cats` model - that's where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the route needs to start with a front slash

change:

```
Route::get('cats/create', function() {
```

to:

```
Route::get('/cats/create', function() {
```

final output:

```
Route::get('/cats/create', function() {
    $cat = new Cat;
    return View::make('cats.edit')
    ->with('cat',$cat)
    ->with('method','post');
});
```

Comment: I've never had to to that, it's always just worked for me without the first slash character.